# Old video card problem

Tags: video, graphics, resolution

I have an old Toshiba Laptop with a very old graphic card **"Trydent CyberAladdin P4 v6.x"**

After installing of Ubuntu 10.04, my screen resolution is 800x600 and this is a maximum size? I can not find a video driver for my video card.

Can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the Trident (not Trydent) drivers :

```
 sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-trident
```

And restart your computer.